# What are the built-in tables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there any built-in table in SQL Server 2008 ? If Yes, Please help me make list of built-in tables in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: You mean, system tables?  Tables in the master database?  Something else?

Comment: You should get yourself acquainted with [SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Yes. I want to read the memory related data, if any.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following SQL script against your database instance, you'll see them :)

```
SELECT * from sys.objects
WHERE type = 's'
```

Or, if you're *too lazy*. Here's one I made earlier:

> sysrscols 
>   sysrowsets 
>   sysallocunits 
>   sysfiles1 
>   syspriorities 
>   sysfgfrag 
>   sysphfg 
>   sysprufiles 
>   sysftinds 
>   sysowners 
>   sysprivs 
>   sysschobjs 
>   syscolpars 
>   sysnsobjs 
>   syscerts 
>   sysxprops 
>   sysscalartypes 
>   systypedsubobjs 
>   sysidxstats 
>   sysiscols 
>   sysbinobjs 
>   sysaudacts 
>   sysobjvalues 
>   sysclsobjs 
>   sysrowsetrefs 
>   sysremsvcbinds 
>   sysxmitqueue 
>   sysrts 
>   sysconvgroup 
>   sysdesend 
>   sysdercv 
>   syssingleobjrefs 
>   sysmultiobjrefs 
>   sysguidrefs 
>   syscompfragments 
>   sysftstops 
>   sysqnames 
>   sysxmlcomponent 
>   sysxmlfacet 
>   sysxmlplacement 
>   sysobjkeycrypts 
>   sysasymkeys 
>   syssqlguides 
>   sysbinsubobjs 
>   syssoftobjrefs

Comment: @user1365604 No problems, if this was the correct answer please click the tick next to it to mark it as correct. Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0):

To list all the tables for all the databases in the system, run the following script

```
sp_msforeachdb 'select "?" AS db, * from [?].sys.tables'
```

Comment: These aren't just the 'system tables'